# Is it possible to prevent org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException via configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Is it possible to configure Hibernate in a way that an object won't be queried twice in a session?

When saving objects I sometimes get the error `Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session`

It means that Hibernate returns two different objects for the same entity. Is it possible to tell Hibernate to hold a cache from each entity and to return the cached objects if it was already queried?

This would prevent `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException`.

EDIT:

My issue is that the session is closed between two queries. See below for an example code:

```
Session hibernateSession = FactoryBuilder.getCurrentSession();

// First request starts
hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
Car car1 = getById(Car.class, 4);
hibernateSession.getTransaction().commit();
// First request ends

// Second request starts
Car car2 = getById(Car.class, 4);
car2.setName("My new name 2h");
saveOrUpdate(car2);

car1.setName("My new name 1y");
saveOrUpdate(car1);
// Second request ends
```

Background is that after a request was being performed the hibernate session is closed but in order to improve performance, the Car objects are kept into memory.

When the next request hits the server the Car objects which are in memory are not returned by Hibernate. Instead Hibernate fetches new Cars from the database which causes the error.

Is there a way to configure Hibernate to returns theses objects? Hibernate is aware about these objets otherwise it won'
t throw this error.

Comment: Hibernate already does that. It's the first level cache.

Comment: Hibernate won't query same object in a single session as it uses a first level cache. You said you are getting the error while saving. So this is probably because you are trying to save multiple entities with same identifier(PK) in a single session

Comment: You are right. The session is closed between two fetch. I edited my question.